# Htaccess Redirect issues in joomla

Tags: .htaccess

Please help me with a redirect issue.

I am trying to redirect from  http://www.project/index.php/blog to http://www.project/blog.

I tried the following but it did not work

```
RewriteRule ^(blog)$ ./index.php/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^index.php/blog(.*)$ http://www.project/blog$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Glad I could help @TausifAnwar. You know where we are if you have any more questions!  If the answer was correct, then please do select it as the correct answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the requested path info at `index.php`, you might use this [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```