# Htaccess Redirect issues in joomla project

Tags: .htaccess

I have a redirect issue.

I am trying to redirect from http://www.project.com/index.php to http://www.project.com

I tried the following, but it goes one step back to any `index.php` like that.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've just realised this is a repeat of a question you've already asked and that I've already answered...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess Redirect issues in joomla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463416/htaccess-redirect-issues-in-joomla)

Answer (score 1):

To remove index.php use:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

However, you can also use the below as an alternative (but it will require you to enable mod_rewrite for it to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```